Do I need to add Requested value to the output of Simulink PID block?
I'm very new to Simulink PID block, I'm trying to implement the PID controller for below requirement see link/attachment. If I'm using Simulink PID block do I need to add Requested value to the output of PID?
Applying PID to control system stability
I tired to simulate as per images but since I do not have a proper plant model, I'm unable to figure out if the implementation is correct. Most of example available in the Internet doesn't add requested to the PID block output.
Please clarify whether to add requested value to the Simulink PID block is required or not required.
Thank you in advance.
